# Change selection on a ComboBoxEditSettings inside a grid using KeyUp/Down

Tags: wpf, xaml, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I'm working with a ComboBox inside a grid using the ComboBoxEditSeting and I want to be able to on tab into the control, if the user press KeyDown/KeyUp, drop down the list of options and the user can navigate between them. I know that at the moment this is possible if I press Ctrl+KeyUp/Down, but I want it without the combination with control. How can achieve this?

Here's a peak of the code that I have till now:

```
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="{x:Static model:PromptFieldNames.WFieldName}" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.SubmitTo}" HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Left" MinWidth="100"  Width="250">
    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
        <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Ws, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                  ValueMember="Id" IsTextEditable="False"
                                  DisplayMember="Name" ImmediatePopup="True" />
    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
</dxg:GridColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Key Events are handled at the grid level, so you have to create a GridControl class descendant and override its OnPreviewKeyDown method:

```
            public class MyGridControl : GridControl
            {
                protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (!(View.ActiveEditor is ComboBoxEdit))
                    {
                        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
                        return;
                    }

                    if (e.Key == Key.Down)
                        ((ComboBoxEdit)View.ActiveEditor).SpinDown();

                    if (e.Key == Key.Up)
                        ((ComboBoxEdit)View.ActiveEditor).SpinUp();

                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
```

But you have to activate an Editor by F2 key or by Cell click.